# Android udp port

Tags: android, udp, port

i want to send a udp packet from my laptop to an android device, i write a simple App for that but it doesn't work, i think that the port(5554) that i have been used is the problem.
Code:

`private void runUdpServer()

```
    EditText RecieveText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText check = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    String lText;
    byte[] lMsg = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
    DatagramSocket ds = null;
    RecieveText.setText("try1");
    try {
```

`RecieveText.setText("try2");
             ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT); // i think the problem is here

            //disable timeout for testing

            if (ds != null){RecieveText.setText("connected");}`
           else {RecieveText.setText("not connected");}

```
        RecieveText.setText("try");
```

`ds.receive(dp);
            lText = new String(lMsg, 0, dp.getLength());
            Log.i("UDP packet received", lText);
            RecieveText.setText(lText);
            check.setText("port opened");`

      ``` } catch (SocketException e) {``
            check.setText("SocketException"); ```

e.printStackTrace();

```
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        check.setText("port didn't open");

    } finally {
        if (ds != null) {
            ds.close();
            RecieveText.setText("not connected1");
        }
        else {RecieveText.setText("not connected1");}
    }
    check.setText("end");
     if (ds != null){RecieveText.setText("connected");}
```

`else {RecieveText.setText("not connected");}
}
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it is a port issue... print your error log to have a better idea of faillure.... any way try this ... not checked for any typo.... Also keep in mind that any networking task is better to be inside an async task...

```
    int port =1855; ///any port that you want > 1024
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //////send socket
    int eport = 1616;
    InetAddress eip = null;
    try {
        eip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");  ////SERVER IP ADDRESS 
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    DatagramSocket esocket = null;
    try {
        esocket = new DatagramSocket(eport);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

///SENDING

```
   byte[] send= new byte[60*1024];
     DatagramPacket send_packet = new DatagramPacket(send, send.length);


    try {
        socket.send(send_packet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//////Start receive
        while(true)
        {

```
        byte[] message = new byte[60*1024];
        DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);


        try {
            socket.receive(recv_packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    ///Do something whit recv_packet
}
```